# OpenLayers - Problems With WPSClient

Tags: openlayers-2, wps

I am trying to incorporate a WPS running in GeoServer into an OpenLayers client.  I am using [this](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/wps-client.html) simple example as my reference.

Using either a local install of OpenLayers.js (v 2.12), or the http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js,
I get an error when the WPSClient is created.  In Firefox, I get OpenLayers.WPSClient is not a constructor.

Can anyone help me out with this error?

Comment: I have the same problem of user890. I am using the API version 2.11. Of course OpenLayers.WPSClient class is not written inside. But when I try to use the version given before (Release 2.13 dev) in my web portal, this library looks to have some errors and I can't use it in Eclipse + Tomcat 7. I don't know what can be happening. When I use the same library in the same project in Dreamweaver without web server I am able to use the library. Does anyone know what is wrong with it? Thanks in advance
Rafael

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is due to WPSClient class not available in your API version.
Try this [OpenLayers.js](http://openlayers.org/dev/OpenLayers.js) instead of yours. You are using a stable version of API for a developement version of WPS example. If you open the link below you can see OpenLayer.WPSClient class written inside the js file.

Hope that helps